# How to fetch and create dataframe faster in R

Tags: r, dbi

I'm using following query in R, the Query Run time is < 50 sec to fetch millions of records however while converting the output into dataframe using dbGetQuery it takes almost an hour. Please suggest how can I optimize the dataframe creation process in R.

Please help me with a faster approach to fetch query output in R dataframe.

```
# Define your start_date as needed
custom_start_date <- "YYYY-MM-DD"  # Replace with your desired start date

# Construct the SQL query with generic variable names
custom_sql_query <- sprintf("
WITH FirstInstance AS (
  SELECT var1, 
         MIN(var2)
  FROM delta.var3.var4
  WHERE date(var2) >= date('%s')
  GROUP BY var1
)
SELECT var1, 
       var5,
       var6,
       var7,
       var8,
       var9,
       var10,
       var11
FROM delta.var3.var4
INNER JOIN FirstInstance 
ON var1 = var1
AND var2 = var2", custom_start_date)
# Fetch the data
df <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_query)
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Comment: You "know" that the data download takes less than 50 seconds, how? (I'm not doubting it, just trying to verify the metrics used.)

Comment: @r2evans - It is based on my observation, sometimes it takes more than a minute. Also, it's not download it's query run time in R.

Comment: I don't understand. You call `dbGetQuery(.)`, and R knowingly "hangs". Roughly 50 seconds later, you "know" that all of the data has been downloaded to your computer, yet R is still not returning to the console. An hour later, you finally get the normal R `>` prompt back? If that is right, how are you observing that all of the data has been downloaded and it does something else for the remaining 55+ minutes?

Comment: @r2evans I have added the query sucess message in the question.

Comment: I do not find progress indicators to be a reliably source for anything to do with database connections. There are at least two major contributors to slow queries: the time it takes the DBMS itself to optimize/analyze the query in order to take advantage of indices; and the amount of time it takes over the network connection to transfer all of the data. From the perspective of the interactive component of R, they are confounded. If you don't hit the table indices correctly, it can result in a "table scan", which can add an order of magnitude to the query analyzing step, nothing to do with R.

Comment: One _objective_ measure of when things are happening is network traffic: if you have a network bandwidth monitor and have nothing substantial running, you can _infer_ when the data download starts and when the data download stops based on the "mountain" in the graph of network I/O (nothing in R can see this). From the time that data load stops until you get an interactive prompt in R is the amount of time "dataframe creation" takes, usually it's a small fraction of the data download time, but there are factors that might contribute to slowed creation.

Comment: dbGetQuery is a wrapper that calls dbSendQuery, then dbFetch, ensuring that the result is always free-d by dbClearResult. so perhaps lessons can be learned from timing the synchronous dbSendQuery time, seperately from the dbFetch time